# Does Win32API differ 32bit version and 64bit version?

Tags: windows, api, resources, 64-bit, handle

Seems all Win32 APIs are all 32-bit version, no matter my Windows installed is 32-bit or 64-bit. If I call `CreateWindow`, the HANDLE returned will be a pointer to a `_HANDLE`, which is a structure of `struct {int unused;}`.

So both 32-bit Windows and 64-bit Windows are using Windows API which manages resource in 32-bit style, right?

If this is the case, then the upper limit number of files/GUI handles of a process, is the same between 32/64-bit windows? In other words, besides having more memory, a 64-bit Windows process cannot hold more system resources, comparing with 32-bit process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Seems all win32 api are all 32bit version, not matter my windows installed is 32bit or 64bit.

That's not correct, and the example you provide (`HANDLE`) shows this as well: It is a **pointer**, so it's 64 bits wide on a 64-bit version of Windows. The fact that it points to some arbitrary structure<sup>1</sup> (`struct { int unused; };`) is not relevant. The structure contents aren't used<sup>2</sup>.

With that out of the way, you can see, that the theoretical maximum of kernel objects referenced by a `HANDLE` type is higher on 64-bit Windows than it is on 32-bit Windows. The practical limits are usually lower than those, for many reasons. Too many to list them all, but here is a compilation of related articles you may find interesting:

- [On the unanswerability of the maximum number of user interface objects a program can create](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060901-11/?p=29883)
- [Does Windows have a limit of 2000 threads per process?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050729-14/?p=34773)
- [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Physical Memory](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2008/07/21/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-physical-memory/)
- [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Virtual Memory](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2008/11/17/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-virtual-memory/)
- [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Paged and Nonpaged Pool](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/03/10/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-paged-and-nonpaged-pool/)
- [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Processes and Threads](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/07/05/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads/)
- [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Handles](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/09/29/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-handles/)
- [Pushing the Limits of Windows: USER and GDI Objects – Part 1](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2010/02/24/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-user-and-gdi-objects-part-1/)
- [Pushing the Limits of Windows: USER and GDI Objects – Part 2](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2010/03/31/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-user-and-gdi-objects-part-2/)

---

<sup>1</sup> *This structure is only used, if the [STRICT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383732.aspx) preprocessor macro is set. If it isn't, a `HANDLE` is just a typedef for a `void*`.*
<sup>2</sup> *The structure serves the purpose to prevent certain categories of programmer errors, like assigning a `HANDLE` to an `int`. Internal to the system, it's the handle **value** that's meaningful.*